# Remove 'Powered by Google' logo from Places API Dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I'd like to remove this logo from the Google Places API drop-down. I'd like to put it elsewhere on the page as I think it kind of detracts from the aesthetics of the drop-down, especially when I've got multiple drop-downs in a row, all with the same logo.

[image: Google Places Dropdown]

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to inspect the element in order to see it's markup (I'm using Chrome, each time I try to inspect it, the drop-down disappears).

The Developer Policies says:

> If your application displays Places API data on a map, that map must
>   be provided by Google.
>
> If your application displays Places API data on a page or view that
>   does not also display a Google Map, you must show a "Powered by
>   Google" logo with that data. For example, if your application displays
>   a list of Places on one tab, and a Google Map with those Places on
>   another tab, the first tab must show the "Powered by Google" logo.

It doesn't state that it must be included on the dropdown, just that the logo must be included with the data. I have a container with multiple input fields in all making requests to the Places API, surely then I can just have the logo inside that container with all the input fields in?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that goes against the Google Maps terms and conditions.

Comment: Yeah, at the very least check, but I suspect you'll find that that's the case.

Comment: "Places API responses may include Listings provider attributions in HTML format that must be displayed to the user as provided. Any links included in the HTML must be preserved. We recommend placing this information below any search results or Place Details information" - https://developers.google.com/places/policies#attribution_requirements

Comment: That is only a recommendation though, not a rule.

Comment: what is the URL for the websites it's on and i'll see?

Comment: The "Powered by Google" image is very simple to remove... Clearly most us see it as unethical, though.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/policies

Comment: I do not share the other's concern over the appropriateness of what you are trying to do. It is not for me to judge, and this problem could be adapted to others like it that have no such concern. 

I do not suspect it would be all that hard to inspect with Chrome. I may be wrong. Do you have a URL we can see where this behavior happens?

Comment: I managed to find an answer, iGanja. Thanks though.

Comment: what do you mean by "against terms and policies" and "unethical"? it clearly says that if you also use the google map on your page you don't have to use "powered by google" logo in the searchbox as well, since the logo "powered by google" is already displayed on the map itself. why would you clog user interface with duplicate "powered by google" logos if the map-searchbox interface already has the "powered by google" logo included? there is absolutely nothing unethical or illegal about it